# How to focus next element on ngFor in a form angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Now i know there are plenty of answers for this, trust me i am actually trying to figure it out but i can't get this feature to work on my app. I hope this question will not be defined as duplicate.

My question is how do i give focus to the last element of a ngFor when pressing a button?

---

I have a `*ngFor` that i use to loop through some `FormArray` like this:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let reg of registrations.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <td>
       <ng-select #peopleSelect [selectOnTab]="true" appendTo="body" placeholder="Select Operator" 
        formControlName="peopleId" style="width: 250px">
         <ng-option *ngFor="let people of peopleList" [value]="people.peopleId">Name Surname</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Here:

- `registrations` is a getter that gets a `FormArray` and i loop through it's controls
- `ng-select` is a select element [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)
- `#peopleSelect` is the ID given to a select element in the loop

In my ts file i do this:

```js
@ViewChildren('peopleSelect') peopleSelectEl!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
addRow(): void { // method used in my app to add a row to the FormArray
 this.peopleSelectEl.last.nativeElement.focus(); // here nativeElement is undefined
}
```

In the code above:

- using `this.peopleSelectEl.last.nativeElement.focus()` will get me `undefined`
- doing `console.log(this.peopleSelectEl.last)` will get me this: [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZMk.png)

What am i doing wrong in my code? Why doing `focus()` or even console logging `.nativeElement` won't work?

### UPDATE

`console.log(this.peopleSelectEl)` gives this: [image: select log]

Don't know if this could help but i am trying to do all this inside a bootstrap modal... that i open from the parent component

Comment: What do you want to achieve? In your question you want to select a 'next' element, in the description you you last, and something called addRow().. whats your goal? To focus the last option? to add a registrations.control? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import { NgSelectComponent } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@ViewChildren('select') peopleSelectEl!: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.peopleSelectEl.last.focus();
}
```

[working example is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-qad7p8?file=app/app.component.ts)